# Storing bold/italic text, images in Flask backend

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

I am working on a Post - It/Sticky notes project where I'm using flask as the backend and React front end. The user while typing notes can make the text as bold or italics, in the future I also want the ability to add photos/voice recordings to it. Basically, I want to know how do you store data that IS NOT plain text into the database,I. E. how do I send this bold/italic text from the front end and store it in a flask database.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

How about storing a JSON object, like:

```
storeThis = {
    'type': "text",
    'text': "Hey, there!",
    'style': "font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:red;"
}

storeThis = {
    'type': "img",
    'src': "http://.......jpg",
    'style': "height:100px;width:120px;"
}
```

Photos & voice recordings are best stored as blobs in the cloud or on your server, then ref'd with a url.

**Update**

For more granular styling, you could store each as an HTML string.  Example:

```
storeThis = 'Pick up <span style="font-size:20px;font-weight:bold;color:red;">dry cleaning</span>'
```

Then, in the template, use the `|safe` filter to display as html:

{{ storeThis|safe }}

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. But I don't think it would work in this case cause my notes are going to be both both(or any other format) along with plain text. For example, my note is "Pick up dry cleaning", in which only the words "dry cleaning" are made bold/italic/underlined etc. I don't know how to store this in the back end db